# Adding headers after RESTAdapter initialization

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to add an `Authorization` header to my adapter's request after the adapter has been initialized and used.  I can add headers in a static way at the time I create my `ApplicationAdapter`, but I can't seem to get it use the headers in subsequent REST calls.  I am trying this:

```
var auth= "Basic " + hash;
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
    headers: {
        Authorization: auth
    }
});
```

I have debugged `RESTAdapter` in the `ajax` method, and the test for `adapter.headers` is always `undefined`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't address the fact that the recommended approach is not working in ember-data. I say recommended since:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L88

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L162
and other places in that file.

Further, the issue the OP brings up with of undefined specifically happens here:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L619

So, the following simply does not work:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
  headers: {token: 'reopen_token (NO WORK)' }
});
```

I've tried to point to this out as an issue but it got closed within an hour:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1820

Hopefully core will decide to either fix this or remove the comments. But, yes, for now it seems you have to hijack jQuery ajax setup, Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter, or override the `ajax` on the adapter yourself.

**EDIT:** So after getting some more feedback from Ember devs, it looks like the core of this issue is trying to reopen an instance already created. So using a computered property when it's defined (so it will update as desired) seems to be the advised approach. Hope that helps (there's a recently merged pull request that makes this more obvious in the comments of referenced file:https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1818/files#diff-1d7f5a5b77898df15de501c3c38d4829R108 )

**EDIT 2:** Got this working in my app so here's the code in case someone else gets stuck:

```
//app.js
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  headers: function() {
    return {
      token: this.get('App.authToken') || localStorage.getItem('token')
    };
  }.property("App.authToken")
});

//login-controller.js (only action shown..assume `data` has user/pass)
  actions: {
    login: function() {
        $.post('/token/', data).done(function(user) {
          App.set('authToken', user.token);
          //Above will trigger adapters's header computed property to update

          // Transition to previous attempted route
          var attemptedTransition = self.get('attemptedTransition');
          if(attemptedTransition) {
            attemptedTransition.retry();
          }
          else {
            self.transitionToRoute('yourapproute');
          }
        })
        .fail(function(response) { 
          //fail handling omitted
        });
```

Comment: This mostly solves the problem in what I believe is the most idiomatic Ember way. The only problem I have is that we have to store the token on the main app namespace itself, when I'd prefer to keep it associated with my session controller. Is it possible to grab the property from a controller for a computed header?

Comment: Instead of watching `App`, try using `.property().volatile()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are already introduced in official API document.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization

- Use computed property with session injection
- or just use `volatile` computed property

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$.ajaxPrefilter` to add custom headers (or params).

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

```
Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, oriOptions, jqXHR ) {
  var auth= "Basic " + hash;
  jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
});
```

Comment: This answer is accepted since it solves the issue...but not because you found a way to get reopen to work right?There are several ways to hijack this in jQuery, but there should be an idiomatic Ember way imo. Especially if you're using jQuery for other things in a mashup and don't want to do things globally.