# Ember.js Dynamically setting REST auth-token in RESTAdapter headers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This SO post ([Adding headers after RESTAdapter initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490476/adding-headers-after-restadapter-initialization)) is my guide for coding my code:

My auth REST get succesfully returning a token. I use AJAX directly not through ember-data coz this is only login and getting an authorization token (guide at embercast)

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'api/auth',
    dataType: "json",
    data: postData,
    success: function(response){
      self.set('errorMessage', response.message);

      if (response.success) {

        self.set('token', response.token);
        self.set('loginstatus', 'success');

        var appController = self.get('controllers.application');
        appController.set('token', response.token);
        App.set('authToken', response.token);

        self.transitionToRoute('/');
      }

      if (response.message) {
        //console.log('login failed');
        //THIS CODE IS FAILED!!!
        //self.get('login').render("login-modal-failed", {
        //  into: 'application',
        //  outlet: 'modal'
        //});
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while processing JSON file.");
    }
  });
```

This is the Chrome Network Info and the protected HOME page once login. The authorization token is printed. (**THIS IS ONLY MY EMBER APP LEARNING AND TESTING**)

[image]

As you can see in the AJAX code, here is the properties setting for the auth token to be put into the RESTAdapter headers dynamically each time user login

```
App.set('authToken', response.token);
```

And this is the RESTAdapter code:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'emberauthslimv3/api',

   headers: {
      'AUTH-TOKEN': function() {
         return {
           token : this.get('App.authToken') || localStorage.getItem('token')
         }
       }.property('App.authToken')
   }
});
```

I already try various combination of the headers setting, trust me, I do this for about 2 days now, and never succesfully put the token into the headers.

When I look in the chrome networks info, the headers that I got is this

```
AUTH-TOKEN:[object Object]
```

[image]

Any help/pointers is appreciated :D

**UPDATE**

After testing various combination and still fail, I give up and just use the most simple hack, the ajaxPrefiler haha. At least it works:

```
      if (response.success) {
        Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, oriOptions, jqXHR ) {
          jqXHR.setRequestHeader("AUTH-TOKEN", response.token);
        });

        self.transitionToRoute('/');
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

First you have taken a bad reference link when you have Ember docs for this. Problem is the headers implementation in ApplicationAdapter. You are returning objects with every header property.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: function() {
    return {
      "AUTH-TOKEN": Ember.get('App.authToken') || localStorage.getItem('token')
    };
  }.property().volatile()
});
```

BTW here is the link. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization

Comment: Using your answer, the AUTH-TOKEN is not even inserted into the header.

Comment: using your updated answer, there is AUTH-TOKEN in the header but the content is still the same: AUTH-TOKEN:[object Object]

Comment: I give up haha, so for now I'll just use the Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(). It works

Comment: i implemented here and its working fine https://github.com/thecodejack/lecture-mvc/blob/master/app/adapters/application.js#L5 but i observed 1 issue..if i implement a specific model adapter as rest and don't pass header info since ApplicationAdapter is implemented(with those info), that model rest calls aren't having those headers...

Comment: I notice you're using ember-cli, cool :D. I'm just started using it myself and will try again the dynamic headers setting in the RESTAdapter

Comment: yea..actually the link i shared is kind of reference to all important emberjs concepts i building up :) ...added headers part once you asked  this question...