# Header customization failed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to add a Authorization header in my ajax request but I can't get to it.

```js
import Ember from 'ember'

AppsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    return Ember.RSVP.hash
      count: $.getJSON window.Cockpit.API_URL + "apps/count/" + params.year
      accumulation: $.getJSON window.Cockpit.API_URL + "apps/accumulation/" + params.year

  setupController: (controller, model, queryParams) ->
    controller.set 'model', model.count
    controller.set 'accumulation', model.accumulation
    controller.set 'param', queryParams.params.apps.year

export default AppsRoute
```

I extended the RESTAdapter class like that :

```js
import DS from 'ember-data'

AppAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  headers:
    'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'

export default AppAdapter
```

But my header is not present in the request.

Can anyone help me ? 
Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490476/adding-headers-after-restadapter-initialization

Comment: Thanks, but following the doc http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization, this is the right way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I have not declared my models.